# Maintain sessions on server side in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, session

I am creating an application in `Reactjs`,`nodejs` and `mongodb`. In it, when user login into website, I am saving current time he logged into application and saving into database. And then **saving userId and jwt into localStorage**. And i implemented a functionality that, user can't logout until he didn't added his schedule for today and didn't send the status report and it is working well.

But when User clear localStorage manually and reload the page, he successfully logout from the application and logout time not saving into db, **which i want to prevent**.

So my concern is that, is there anything in `nodejs`, so that i can save userData into **sessions** on server side except saving it in localStorage?

Comment: There is no way to keep a browser user from just disappearing.  They can either clear local Storage (the way you have it now) or they can clear a cookie if you were using traditional server-side sessions.  Basically in a browser application, you can't control when the user leaves.  They leave when they want to leave whether they've done what you want them to do or not.  You can prevent them from doing anything else when they come back again or navigate to another page (while still logged in) or when they attempt to log in again (until they do what you want), but that's about all you control.

Comment: @jfriend00, If i used express-sesion node modules on server side, then?

Comment: Server-side sessions (like express-session) rely on a browser cookie.  If the user deletes the browser cookie or opens a different browser, then the session is abandoned and that's out of the server control.  Basically, the server can't control when/how the client leaves.

Comment: Thanks @jfriend00, one more question. If i saved session Id in hidden field instead of cookies. then?

Comment: I don't get what you're trying to do.  A hidden field would only be sent to the server as part of a POST request, right, not even navigating between pages?  I don't understand what you're trying to do or how you're app works.

Comment: @jfriend00, I want to save user sensitive information like "jwt or userId" while he logged in and user must be logout, when he clicks on logout button not by any other way like clearing localstorage or cookies etc which is done on client side.

So, How can i do above?

Comment: You can't force a user to push a logout button.  They can always abandon their session at any time no matter how you implement it.  You can detect a lack of client activity (with some sort of timeout) on the server and do an auto-logout, but obviously you can't force the user to do anything before that happens.  It sounds to me like you need to fix your design to be more compatible with how client-server computing works.

Answer (score 0):

@Rajat —- transmit jwt or userid via websocket to nodejs and keep a list of active logins. If user does a local flush and logs in again — caution them that they have to repeat everything. Maybe easier to transmit data as they enter via websocket or use package like express-session